Was a Wagner flag flying over the fort in Kidal, Mali?
Radio France Internationale (RFI) claims that this a flag of the Wagner Group flying over a colonial fortress in Kidal, Mali. back in Nov. 2023, when it was captured from Azawad rebels in the Battle of Kidal.

However the photo appears extraordinarily blurry to me to make such a definitive statement, and the Malian government dismissed it as 'fake news'.
Is there some other way to have more certainty over the exact flag flown over the fort Nov. 22-26, 2023? (The flag raised on the 26th was clearly the Malian one, there are much clearer photos of that one in the same RFI piece.)

I understand you don't like my description of the Wagner group, which I based off the Wikipedia description, but I would encourage you to include some description because most readers are not going to have a clue who they are or why this might be important.

@Oddthinking: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/88666/what-is-wagner-part-of-officially-these-days

That doesn't help at all.

Does RFI indicate whether they are saying this is a Wagner flag based on the evidence of this photo alone, or if they have some other evidence (e.g. eyewitness reports)?

@NateEldredge: from the text, apparently Wagner claimed it was their flag on Telegram. And a white hand [of the cameraman] shows up in the video.

The photo isn't too blurred to say that it's black-and-whiteness bears no resemblance to the Wagner flag, as shown.
Test that for yourselves by magnifying the Wagner flag using any software you like, and report back whether when it blurred as much as the  flag on the tower, they looked at all similar.
